# Mitm attack problem

Tags: linux

I have a problem with implementing this attack.

I have a kali linux machine on vmware workstation. My router is - 192.168.1.1 My victim ip is - 192.168.1.254

```
arpspoof -i eth0 -t 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.254

arpspoof -i eth0 -t 192.168.1.254 192.168.1.1
```

I changed

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward to value 1.
```

And after check arp -a on victim machine the mac address of the router still the same , and if i ping some ip even to my router i get requested timed out on victim machine CMD.

Comment: The problem isn't from the attack itself, try the attack on another victim, from another machine, or even change the IPs. sometime it fails for no reason! ... and let the arpspoof runs for several minutes.

Comment: Have you launch the two commands in the same time ?

Comment: @Emadeddin I changed the ip to 192.168.1.19 and it is still does not work.
let the arpspoof run ? Ok i will try it .. its the first time things like that happend

Comment: @Sorcha Within a few seconds.

Comment: Check the victim is seeing it (can't see why it wouldn't but we all know what assumption is the mother of) with tcpdump or similar, or at least check it is being sent by the attack machine.

Comment: @Michael I checked arp with wireshark and i saw 'duplicate' of ip address .. maybe it is the problem ? 

by the way , i check again the arp - a of the victim.
and i saw the router address gets the mac of the real machine , not the virtual machime (kali) . 

i mean - 
The arp table of windows7 victim computer after arp spoof change the mac address of the router to my another machine win7 machine. not to the kali machine on the real host

Comment: @Antonio Nothing wrong with your commands so it must be a network issue. Just to make sure, when you changed /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward you only added a 1 right. Not 1. as indicated in your post?

Comment: @Joe The value of the file ip_forward is 1.
cat ip_forward prints 1

Comment: A few things just to make sure. Are you running the arpspoof commands in different command line windows?

Is the network on the VMs bridged mode?

And you have killed all previous arpspoof sessions with "killall arpspoof"?

Comment: @Joe Indeed different cmd windows.
and of course in bridged mode . and yes i killed all. evel close the machine and open again

Comment: @Antonio Sounds like it should work fine! Only two other options I can think of to test another protocol such as HTTP since TCP can have issues with arp spoofing. Perhaps use driftnet or URLSnarf to test. If even that fails perhaps consider using Ettercap to check if that also fails.

Comment: @Joe I think i know what is the problem. i already post it.
The arpspoof is working but not correctly.
I mean , my victim machine get arp update and change the mac of the router ip to my real machine , but not the kali linux machine. 
I mean , its change the mac to the host who host kali , not to the kali mac

Comment: @Joe

Look:
http://postimg.org/image/676ahby2x/

All those ip addresses got the same mac ! 
This mac belongs to the host who hosts Kali linux machine ! 
how its happennnnnnnnnnnnn

Comment: Can you explain your whole topology? how your attacking VM connected to other victims and the router ? what interfaces are you using?

Comment: @Emadeddin I Really do not know why .. but i have another computer and started there kali linux and did arp spoof and it works.

Comment: I think your hosting OS changing the source of arp packets to its mac, be sure to put your network interface on bridged mode in VM settings, maybe you are attacking through a NAT network between your VM and the host.

Comment: @Emadeddin i connected network cable and its works from the laptop now .. 
Wifi was the problem

Comment: your were using wifi as eth0 through the VM ? I will post it as an answer, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

As a result from the comments, the problem is **solved** by changing the working interface from WiFi to Ethernet.

the connection was made through the host's WiFi card, but the VM sees it as Ethernet card, and that caused compatibility issues.
Use a USB WiFi adapter will help you avoid that kind of problems on virtual machines.

Comment: When i think about it
on wifi network the linux not should show me wlan0 ?

Comment: No. on virtual machines the wifi card is showed as ethernet card, you must install Kali as a native OS so the wifi card appears as wlan. or you can use a USB wifi card.

Comment: So what was the problem ? with network cable it works.

Comment: Compatibility issue.